# Create an array of a class, passing in individual values in arrays as arguments

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I feel like I am overlooking something basic. I'm looking for an elegant way of doing this:

```
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(ranks.length);
for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
    cards.add(new Card(ranks[i],suits[i],values[i]));
}
```

Intellj came up with:

```
cards = IntStream.range(0, ranks.length).mapToObj(i -> new Card(ranks[i], suits[i], values[i])).collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(ranks.length)));
```

but that feels like a major overkill. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How did you initialise `ranks`, `suits` and `values`? Did you hard code them or are the values from somewhere?

Comment: @Sweeper they are String arrays passed to the constructor, hardcoded on the other side from where they're passed (but just as an example)

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the three arrays and then creating cards from them, why not hardcode the card array: `{ new Card(...), new Card(...), new Card(...) }` if you don't like the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your for loop approach, but if you want to use `Stream`s, you can simplify the `collect` part (you can do without the custom capacity and `List` implementation):

```
cards = IntStream.range(0, ranks.length).mapToObj(i -> new Card(ranks[i], suits[i], values[i])).collect(Collectors.toList());
```